Capture only if string exists, if not ignore
I have a string like this:

blabla and (ee.xybfkr_eer in (:something) or 'Y'=:see)

I would like to capture only the string ee.xybfkr_eer in (:something) in the group.
but sometimes the string is without ee. part:

blabla and (xybfkr_eer in (:something) or 'Y'=:see)

If this is the case, then I would like to capture the group as xybfkr_eer in (:something).
The string ee can differ, so contain other alphabetic characters.
So far, the code is:
String command = "blabla and (ee.xybfkr_eer in (:something) or 'Y'=:see)";
String patternText = "(?si).*\\W((\\w+\\.)?\\w*\\sin\\s*\\(\\s*:something\\s*\\)).*";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(patternText).matcher(command);

Assert.assertTrue(matcher.matches());
System.out.println(matcher.group(1).trim());

But the
(\\w+\\.)?

part is not capturing ee. if available. This should work if ee. available, then capture it, otherwise if not exists ignore. Can somebody help me to be able to capture ee. part also if available?
I am using Java 8.

Sounds like a job for a tokenizer/parser!

You could make the first part non greedy .*?\\W but if you know that it should not cross matching a parenthesis, then you can also use a negated character class [^()]*\\(

Why are you using  \W to match (? Why not just use \\(?

I suggest you to use "(?i)\\(((\\w+\\.)?\\w*\\hin\\h*\\(\\h*:something\\h*\\))" as regex pattern and use .find() instead of .matches()

You can use: String stringIn = "blabla y (ee.xybfkr_eer en (:algo) o 'Y'=:ver) "; and System.out.println( stringIn.substring( stringIn.indexOf( "(" ) + 1, stringIn.indexOf( ")" ) + 1));, is easy, eficient... and not uggly.

Thank you @anubhava . Your solution is working fine. If you like, please, post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

You may use this regex in Java:
(?i)\(((\w+\.)?\w*\hin\h*\(\h*:something\h*\))

Or in Java:
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
   "(?i)\\(((\\w+\\.)?\\w*\\hin\\h*\\(\\h*:something\\h*\\))" );

PS: Make sure to use Matcher#find() instead of Matcher#matches() that attempts to match complete input.
RegEx Demo
RegEx Details:

(?i): Turn on ignore case mode
\(: Match literal (
(: Start capture group #1

(\w+\.)?: capture group #2 that is an optional match to match 1+ word characters and then a literal .
\w*: Match 0 or more word characters
\h: Match a horizontal whitespace
in: Match text in
\h*: Match 0 or more horizontal whitespaces
\(: Match literal (
\h*: Match 0 or more horizontal whitespaces
:something: Match text :something
\h*: Match 0 or more horizontal whitespaces
\): Match literal )


): End capture group #1


Try:
(?<=\()[\w.]+\h+in\h+\(:something\)

See: regex101

Explanation:

(?<= ... ): asserts that to the left of the string there is a

\(: literal opening parenthesis



After this match (capture group 0) what you want:

[\w.]+: Any number or wordcharacters and dots
\h+: followed by some amount of horizontal whitespaces
in: a literal "in"
\h+: more horizontal whitespaces
\(:something\): and literal "(:something)"

